# Multiprocessing a member function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of objects and need to call a member function of every object. Is it possible to use multiprocessing for that?

I wrote a short example of what i want to do.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Example:
    data1 = 0
    data2 = 3

    def compute():
        self.val3 = 6


listofobjects = []

for i in range(5):
    listofobjects.append(Example())

pool = mp.Pool()
pool.map(listofobjects[range(5)].compute())
```

Comment: First, you need to pass a _function_ to `map`, not the result of calling a function. Also, that function should be something that applies to each element of some sequence. So, you can write a function that takes an object `obj` and calls `obj.compute()` on it (if you don't understand how to do that concisely, just use `def` to define it normally), then pass that function, with `listofobjects` as the sequence of arguments.

Comment: Fix your indentation please (`compute` specifically).

Comment: But meanwhile, your `Example` objects can't be shared between processes in this way. Changes you make in a child won't be visible in the parent. What you usually want to do is `return` a new `Example` instance with the changes. Then `map` will give you a sequence of five new `Example`s that are equivalent to processed versions of the original  five `Example`s. And this can sometimes be as simple as your function being `obj.compute(); return obj`.

Comment: @abarnert. OP is almost right: `map(Example.compute, listofobjects)` is just about right, except for that last bit about not updating the original

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP is not almost right. `Example.compute` is pretty far away from `listofobjects[range[5]].compute()`, far enough away that I don't know that he'd be able to immediately understand what the differences are, or even know what bound methods are. That's why I think he needs to go back to first principles and write a function that takes an `Example` and calls `compute` on it—if he knows that `Example.compute` is exactly that function, great; if not, he can write it explicitly with `def`.

Comment: @abarnert. I see your point, but since I'm basically point wh**ing at the moment, I'll will write a proper answer.

Comment: @abarnert. Posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two conceptual issues that @abarnert has pointed out, beyond the syntactic and usage problems in your "pseudocode". The first is that `map` works with a function that is applied to the elements of your input. The second is that each sub-process gets a *copy* of you object, so changes to attributes are not automatically seen in the originals. Both issues can be worked around.

To answer your immediate question, here is how you would apply a method to your list:

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(Example.compute, listofobjects)
```

`Example.compute` is an *unbound method*. That means that it is just a regular function that accepts `self` as a first argument, making it a perfect fit for `map`. I also use the pool as a context manager, which is recommended to ensure that cleanup is done properly whether or not an error occurs.

The code above would not work because the effects of `compute` would be local to the subprocess. The only way to pass them back to the original process would be to `return` them from the function you passed to `map`. If you don't want to modify `compute`, you could do something like this:

```
def get_val3(x):
    x.compute()
    return x.val3

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    for value, obj in zip(pool.map(get_val3, listofobjects), listofobjects):
        obj.val3 = value
```

If you were willing to modify `compute` to return the object it is operating on (`self`), you could use it to replace the original objects much more efficiently:

```
class Example:
    ...
    def compute():
        ...
        return self

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    listofobjects = list(pool.map(Example.compute, listofobjects))
```

**Update**

If your object or some part of its reference tree does not support pickling (which is the form of serialization normally used to pass objects between processes), you can at least get rid of the wrapper function by returning the updated value directly from `compute`:

```
class Example:
    ...
    def compute():
        self.val3 = ...
        return self.val3

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    for value, obj in zip(pool.map(Example.compute, listofobjects), listofobjects):
        obj.val3 = value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to implement it with return self, but it seems like one of the libraries I use is not working with multiprocessing. I get this error: `TypeError: can't pickle ephem.EarthSatellite objects`

Comment: @Patrick. What library if I might ask? ephem.EarthSatellite sounds like something that I would know something about. If `return self` does not work, then go with the first option. You can shorten it by replacing `return self` with `return self.val3` and skipping the wrapper function.

Comment: It is [pyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/), one of the elements in my object is a pyEphem satellite, but that object is not called/used in the mapped function.

Comment: @Patrick. No, but it probably gets referenced indirectly somehow.

Comment: @Patrick If you need to pass around things that can’t be pickled but seem like they *should* be no problem to pickle, look into `dill` and `cloudpickle`, which are both heavily used by the numeric/scientific and data-processing communities for exactly this purpose (to pass around nontrivial objects without having to write a bunch of custom picklers).

Comment: Ok, I just tried the last update and I still get that Error.

Comment: @Patrick. Could you post a minimal example of code that throws that error? I can't really fix your problem if I have no real idea what it is. The code I posted works with the examples you give in the question, and basically answers your question as posed. It would probably be better if you asked another question, specific to the error you are getting.

Comment: I suspect that the problem in the OP’s real code isn’t pickling his equivalent to `Example`, but his equivalent to `6`. In which case he needs to write a custom pickler for whatever type that is (from pyephem), or use a helper library that already knows how to do that (which I’d bet `dill` has a good chance of knowing).

Comment: @abarnert. I was just updating my comment to reflect that :)

Comment: @Patrick Mad Physicist is right that you should probably ask a separate question on “How do I pickle pyephem objects for multiprocessing”. But you should search on that first, and I’m willing to bet the question and answer already exists. (Especially if `dill` just does it out of the box.) And if that’s your only remaining problem, you should probably accept his answer, as it does answer the original problem you raised in your question.

Comment: I just added an example, thank you for your suggestions. I will take a look at `dill`.

Comment: @Patrick. You should really remove that example into a separate question, since that is what it is.

Comment: @Patrick. Ping me with the question URL when you write it. I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637965/how-do-i-pickle-pyephem-objects-for-multiprocessing) to my other question. Thank you a lot for your help so far!