# How do I pickle pyEphem objects for multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pyephem, dill

I am trying to calculate some values of satellites, the data-generation takes quite long so I want to implement this using multiprocessing.

The problem is that I get this error from pyEphem, `TypeError: can't pickle ephem.EarthSatellite objects`. The pyEphem objects are not used in the functions that I want to parallelize.

This is an example file of my code (minimized).

This is my main file:

**main.py**

```
import ephem
import numpy
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
from SampleSats import Sats


GPS_Satellites = []

SFrames = 1
TLE = ["GPS BIIR-3  (PRN 11)",
       "1 25933U 99055A   18090.43292845 -.00000054  00000-0  00000+0 0  9994",
       "2 25933  51.8367  65.0783 0165007 100.2058 316.9161  2.00568927135407"]
# PRN TLE file from CelesTrak
GPS_Satellites.append(Sats(TLE))
Position = ephem.Observer()
Position.date = '2018/3/31 00:00'  # 1st January 2018 at 00:00 UTC
Position.lon, Position.lat = "36.845663", "-37.161123"   # Coordinates for desired Position

# Calculate Satellites
for Frames in range(SFrames):
    print("Generate Signals for Time: ", Position.date)
    for Sats in GPS_Satellites:  # par
        Sats.compute(Position)

        if ((float(repr(Sats.ephemeris.alt)) * 180 / math.pi) < 5) or (  # Calculate angle above horizon
                (float(repr(Sats.ephemeris.alt)) * 180 / math.pi) > 90):
            Sats.visible = 0
        else:
            Sats.visible = 1

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for value, obj in zip(pool.map(Sats.genSignal, GPS_Satellites), GPS_Satellites):
            obj.Signal = value

    Position.date = Position.date + 6*ephem.second  # 1 Subframe is 6 seconds long
```

This is the Sats class that i wrote:

**sats.py**:

```
import ephem
import numpy

class Sats:
    """Save Satellites as Objects"""

    def __init__(self, tle):
        """:param tle: Two Line Element for ephemeris data also used to get PRN Number from name"""
        self.ephemeris = ephem.readtle(tle[0], tle[1], tle[2])
        self.visible = 1
        self.subframes = 0
        self.CAseq = [x for x in range(1023)]
        self.Out = []
        self.Signal = numpy.zeros(int(300*20*1023), dtype=numpy.int8)

    def compute(self, pos):
        self.ephemeris.compute(pos)
        self.Out.append(numpy.arange(0, 299, 1))
        self.subframes += 1

    def calcData(self, bit, prn):
         return (self.Out[self.subframes - 1].item(0)[0][bit] + self.CAseq[prn]) % 2

    def genSignal(self):
        if(self.visible == 1):
            for bit in range(300):  # 1 Subframe is 300 Bit long
                for x in range(20):  # The PRN Sequence reoccurs every ms -> 20 times per pit
                    for prn in range(1023):  # length of the prn sequence
                        self.Signal[bit*x*prn] = (-1 if (self.calcData(bit, prn))==0 else 1)
        else:
            self.Signal = numpy.zeros(300*20*1023)
        return self.Signal
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PATH_TO_PROJECT/SampleTest.py", line 33, in <module>
    for value, obj in zip(pool.map(Sats.genSignal, GPS_Satellites), GPS_Satellites):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle ephem.EarthSatellite objects
```

Comment: You probably want a list or something like that for the first parameter to `Sats` in `main`.

Comment: Show the line where the error happens and the full traceback.

Comment: Make sure that you can run this code yourself to get the expected error.

Comment: In my code i am reading those parameters from a textfile and they are just used once for initialization of the pyEphem objects.

Comment: That's fine. Just pass in a value that makes sense in your example. At the moment, you are passing in a string for `tle`, but I am pretty sure that's not right. Check by running the code.

Comment: Updated Code + Added Traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is something like this... when you try to pickle a function, it can attempt to pickle `globals()`, so whatever you have in your global namespace is also pickled (just in case your function has a reference to something in `globals()` -- yes, that's unexpected, but that's how it is).  So, an easy fix is to isolate the function you want to pickle in another file -- in this case, put the `multiprocessing` stuff in one file and the other code in another file... so there's less in `globals()` for the pickler to struggle with.  Another thing that might help is to use `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing` -- `multiprocess` uses the `dill` serializer instead of `pickle`, so you have a better chance of serializing objects that will be sent across the workers in the `Pool`.